# Optional Chaining Operator in React and babel

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

In my project I config babel:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015","stage-1", "transform-optional-chaining"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

And this is my `devDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^7.0.0-alpha.19",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
```

When I run the project I get this error:

> Cannot find module 'babel-preset-transform-optional-chaining'

Can anyone explain how to fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`transform-optional-chaining` is a plugin (not a preset). Try changing your babel config to:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015","stage-1"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-optional-chaining"]
}
```

Comment: Also a heads up: alpha/beta releases [shouldn't have `^` at the beginning](https://github.com/babel/babel/commit/2679d67#r28703604) (at least for `babel`) as that means breaking changes will auto-update (might not happen if you have a lock file, but you should still remove them). And off of that: [stage presets have been removed](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/48fe688a10d83486defdda223ac8d8d88057975d/packages/babel-preset-stage-0/README.md#babelpreset-stage-0) in the latest version of babel 7.

Comment: With all of that: I believe "transform-optional-chaining" is part of the stage-1 package, so until you update for Babel 7, you shouldn't need this?

Comment: Thank you. This error fixed but I get another error! Now I get this error: Cannot read property 'loose' of undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the bigger issue is you have a mix of versions of babel, all of which are outdated. "transform-optional-chaining" is already included in "stage-1" presets for babel 7 but [was not back-ported to babel 6](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5905#issuecomment-333281933).

However, to make matters more confusing: [babel has done away with stage-presets](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/48fe688a10d83486defdda223ac8d8d88057975d/packages/babel-preset-stage-0/README.md#babelpreset-stage-0) (and es201x presets were deprecated in Babel 6). So in the latest version of babel, you not only *do* need to list out "transform-optional-chaining", but also every other plugin you're using.

I think the only real option here (if you want to use the latest plugins) is to upgrade to the latest version of Babel 7 - which includes a lot of changes, but you'll have to do it eventually anyway. You can find a [migration guide here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/v7-migration).

I suppose you *could* find an alpha version before before stage-presets were removed but that's just giving yourself more work for the future, and there will likely still be changes that have to be made anyhow.