# How to enable optional chaining with Create React App and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, babeljs, create-react-app

> Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently
>   enabled

I was getting the above error. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602455/optional-chaining-not-enabled-reactnative) and added `"@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.7.4"` into my `devDependencies`.

Then I am getting this error,

> Add @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining (https://git.io/vb4Sk) to
>   the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

So I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125711/optional-chaining-operator-in-react-and-babel/52125752) and added `.babelrc` file into my project's root

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "es2015","stage-1"],
    "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-optional-chaining"]
}
```

This did not seem to do anything. I also heard someone mentioning that `Create React App` does not let you modify babel's configurations. So my question is how can I enable optional chaining **without re-wiring** the whole `CRA`?

**P.S.** I am using `"typescript": "^3.7.2"`, or at least that is what my `package.json` says. I tried `npm install` to ensure it is updated. Not sure if `CRA` doing something weird underneath and using older version of `TypeScript` somehow.

---

**EDIT:**
When I started the project with `CRA`, I believe we were using `TypeScript: 3.6.x`. I wanted to use `Optional Chaining`, so I changed my `package.json` file to `"typescript": "^3.7.2"` then `npm install`. I think the problem is, `TypeScript` knows that I am using `3.7.2`, but `CRA` still have older configuration and I am not sure how I can update that.

Comment: You could use [typescript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining). Optional chaining is now a natively supported function.

Comment: I am using TypeScript `^3.7.2`. Or at least thats what my `package.json` says. I have tried `npm install` too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create-React-App uses babel to transpile the TypeScript so it isn't using your npm installed version of TypeScript. Version 3.3.0 of react-scripts supports TypeScript 3.7. You can install it and use it with:

- `yarn add react-scripts@3.3.0`

  -or-
- `npm install -s react-scripts@3.3.0`

Comment: Can you use optional chaining on `react-scripts 3.3.0` without using TS?

Comment: No - optional chaining is a TypeScript feature that needs to be transpiled to JavaScript to work in browsers or NodeJS.

Answer (score 9):

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.2.0",
    "customize-cra": "^0.4.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.3"
  }
  ...other
}
```

---

**config-overrides.js**

```
const { useBabelRc, override } = require('customize-cra');
module.exports = override(useBabelRc());
```

---

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
}
```

[detailed blogpost](https://medium.com/@adostes/enabling-optional-chaining-in-a-create-react-app-a9f626a515d9)

Comment: I mentioned that in OP, I dont want to re-wire the whole thing. `"So my question is how can I enable optional chaining without re-wiring the whole CRA?"`

Comment: How do I use `customize-cra` if I am already using it to override the config?
Eg: ```module.exports = function override(config) {
  config.resolve.modules = [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'];
  return config;
};```

Answer (score 9):

React scripts 3.3.0 and above supports it. There is no need to install the react-scripts@next.

Just put in the package.json `"react-scripts": "^3.3.0"` and it will work.

Comment: Well, I no longer work with the company I was doing react app configuration for. So I cant really test this easily. But good to know. This might be helpful for the future readers.

Comment: Now that I looked back, its the same thing as @LukeP suggested lol

Comment: @HafizTemuri luke updated his answer. His answer was in the start with react-scripts@next

Comment: I see, clever fellow! +1