# Can I use the "?." syntax in react?

Tags: reactjs, syntax, conditional-statements

I come from Angular where there you have the possibility of calling a property like this: object?.property.

If the object is null your app then not breaks down but it performs like an inline if-statement. As far as I know it is angular specific.

Does anyone know how this "ternary" is called? 
Can one use this syntax in React?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: are your application is written in Typescript as in Angular or your application is in JavaScript?

Comment: This is not something specific to Angular but rather to typescript. You can use it if you have typescript 3.7 or above installed. Check your package.json to see the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the same is called Optional chaining operator. It is not angular specific. In case your react app uses typescript with a version 3.7 and above, you might as well go ahead and use it.

Check these articles as well :

https://dev.to/akirautio/optional-chaining-with-react-2l28

[How to enable optional chaining with Create React App and TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093630/how-to-enable-optional-chaining-with-create-react-app-and-typescript)

Usage something like this:

```
  let author = book?.author?.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature coming up in one of the next versions of ECMAScript. You can already use this, but you will need change some configurations to be able to use it. See the article by John Au-Yeung here: https://dev.to/aumayeung/how-to-use-the-optional-chaining-operator-in-your-react-app-right-now-1ocj