# Error is as follows: TypeError: projects.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend, react-thunk

[enter image description here][1]

*I was trying to connect my react frontend to my spring boot backend. I encountered this error. how to resolve this?*
*I am a react and javascript newbie and trying to build a new application. I tried the solution on another stack overflow but nothing seems to be working. *
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaxWI.png

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ProjectItem from "./Project/ProjectItem";
import CreateProjectButton from "./Project/CreateProjectButton";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getProjects } from "../actions/projectActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Projects from './Projects';

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProjects();
  }



 render() {
    const { projects } = this.props.project;

return (
  <div className="projects">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Projects</h1>
          <br />
          <CreateProjectButton />
          <br />
          <hr />
          {projects.map((project) => (<ProjectItem key={project.id} project={project} ></ProjectItem>))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);


 }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  project: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getProjects: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  project: state.project
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getProjects }
)(Dashboard);



 import React,{ useState } from 'react'
import ProjectItem from './Project/ProjectItem';

const Projects = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
        {props.projects.map((project) => (<ProjectItem key={project.id} project={project} ></ProjectItem>))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Projects;

//dispatch redux func

    export const getProjects = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/projects");
  dispatch({
    type: GET_PROJECTS,
    payload: res.data
  });
};
```

Comment: is `state.project.projects` always an array or only after you fetch data from the backend?

Comment: I don't know to be honest

Comment: Hmm, well you must define the initial redux state somewhere. What does that look like?

Comment: `import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import errorReducer from "./errorReducer";
import projectReducer from "./projectReducer";
import backlogReducer from "./backlogReducer";
import securityReducer from "./securityReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  errors: errorReducer,
  project: projectReducer,
  backlog: backlogReducer,
  security: securityReducer
});`

Comment: `import { GET_PROJECTS, GET_PROJECT, DELETE_PROJECT } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  projects: [],
  project: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PROJECTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        projects: action.payload
      };

    case GET_PROJECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        project: action.payload
      };

    
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
`

Comment: At this point I'd do a `console.log(res.data)` when you're fetching your data to make sure it's an array

Comment: `[{"project_id":43,"project_name":null,"github_link":null,"projectIdentifier":"IB123","startedAt":null,"createdOn":null}]{"timestamp":"2021-06-02T01:10:14.090+00:00","status":200,"error":"OK","path":"/api/projects"}`

Comment: Hmm! Now maybe `console.log(projects)` inside your render method (right after you destructure it from `props.project`

Comment: `[{"project_id":43,"project_name":null,"github_link":null,"projectIdentifier":"IB123","startedAt":null,"createdOn":null}]{"timestamp":"2021-06-02T01:20:49.844+00:00","status":200,"error":"OK","path":"/api/projects"}`

Comment: From everything you have told me, it should be rendering. I'd make absolutely sure that these arrays are indeed exactly what's in the `projects` variable and it's not actually nested under another `data` key or something else

Comment: So i tried doing Array.isArray(projects) after destructing. It logs true at first but after the request is made is logs false. How can that be?

Comment: It sounds to me like the data is coming back from your API in an unexpected format. Again, maybe the array is nested under a key? Can you screenshot the `console.log` of the data being returned from the API?

Comment: `[{"project_id":43,"project_name":null,"github_link":null,"projectIdentifier":"IB123","startedAt":null,"createdOn":null},{"project_id":44,"project_name":null,"github_link":null,"projectIdentifier":"NEW","startedAt":null,"createdOn":null}]{"timestamp":"2021-06-02T01:33:01.528+00:00","status":200,"error":"OK","path":"/api/projects"}`

Comment: so I printed the projects on the screen this is what it looks like

Comment: [{"project_id":43,"project_name":null,"github_link":null,"projectIdentifier":"IB123","startedAt":null,"createdOn":null},{"project_id":44,"project_name":null,"github_link":null,"projectIdentifier":"NEW","startedAt":null,"createdOn":null}]{"timestamp":"2021-06-02T01:35:59.645+00:00","status":200,"error":"OK","path":"/api/projects"}

Comment: It has `{"timestamp":"2021-06-02T01:35:59.645+00:00","status":200,"error":"OK","path":"/api/projects"} ` attached to it

Comment: How to get rid of it?

Comment: What if you `console.log(this.props.project)` before the destructuring?

Comment: it shows this `Object { projects: "[{\"project_id\":43,\"project_name\":null,\"github_link\":null,\"projectIdentifier\":\"IB123\",\"startedAt\":null,\"createdOn\":null},{\"project_id\":44,\"project_name\":null,\"github_link\":null,\"projectIdentifier\":\"NEW\",\"startedAt\":null,\"createdOn\":null}]{\"timestamp\":\"2021-06-02T04:01:19.286+00:00\",\"status\":200,\"error\":\"OK\",\"path\":\"/api/projects\"}", project: {} }
​
project: Object {  }
​
`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the optional chaining operator: '?' before the dot notation:

```
projects?.map
```

instead of

```
projects.map
```

Comment: Try to replace the line:
{projects.map((project) => (<ProjectItem key={project.id} project={project} ></ProjectItem>))}

**with this:** 
 {Array.isArray(projects) && projects.map((project) => (<ProjectItem key={project.id} project={project} ></ProjectItem>))}

Comment: It works in the sense I don't have an error anymore but it won't display any content

Answer (score 1):

pay attention to projects props to be a array data to be able to loop over it(not null, undefined, object).
and also you can use  optional chaining operator: '?'

```
(projects?.data)
```

Enabling optional chaining in a create-react-app:

[How to enable optional chaining with Create React App and TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093630/how-to-enable-optional-chaining-with-create-react-app-and-typescript)