# Get a property of an object using forEach even though it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I basically have is an array of objects with several properties, but not all of them have the same properties.

```
const data = [
      {
        car: 12,
        airplane: 42,
        peoples: 2,
      },
      {
        car: 12,
        peoples: 2,
      },
      {
        car: 12,
        airplane: 42,
        peoples: 2,
      },
    ];
```

What I want to do is apply a `filter()` to filter the objects with the condition below. The problem is that there are objects with these properties missing and consequently the code ends up breaking. What is the best way to do this without breaking the code?

```
data.forEach((item) => item.airplane > 5);
```

Comment: it should works this way. what is breaking with your code? please add the error, you get.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const data = [ { car: 12, airplane: 42, peoples: 2 }, { car: 12, peoples: 2 }, { car: 12, airplane: 42, peoples: 2 } ];

const res = data.filter(({ airplane }) => airplane && airplane > 5);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your most succinct option here is to use [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) -- the combination of these two allow you to use some fallback option when some property in the chain is missing.  So you would rewrite your callback as:

```
(item) => (item?.airplane ?? 0) > 5
```

In the case that `item.airplane` is defined, you will get the calculation as expected.  If it is *not*, it will fallback to assessing `0 > 5`.

Comment: I got this error using ReactJs. Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled

Comment: The syntax is supported natively in all the major browser with the exception of IE-- I'd check [this answer for tips on how to enable it in your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093630/how-to-enable-optional-chaining-with-create-react-app-and-typescript)-- my _hunch_ is that you are on an older version of CRA.  For what it is worth, if this is not worth the trouble, any of other answers that do a simple existence/truthiness check before assessing the comparison will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `filter()` and you need to expand a little on your filter logic to check for the property -

```
const result = data.filter((item) => item.airplane && item.airplane > 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you can check if the item exists like so:

```js
const result = data.filter(function(item) {
  if (item.airplane) {
    return item.airplane > 5;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

This even works in strict mode.